# Require.js something not clear

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, require

I am trying to use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) and to load external vendor js and to hide global variables like Backbone or Underscore.

Here's my code:

```
<script data-main="./main" src="<?php echo $rootRequirejs?>/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "/web/js",
        paths: {
            "jquery": "/vendor/js/jquery-1.7.1.min",
            'underscore': '/vendor/js/underscore-min',
            'backbone': '/vendor/js/backbone-min'
        }
    });
```

Here's my questions:

1)
If I go to the javascript console and I write Backbone or underscore they are defined….
I think it should be not accessible from the console but just from my main.js file.
Why they are global?

Comment: About the global, they're still global until you use the `noConflict()` method on them. IIRC, require.js allows you to define a function for these dependencies, so you can return something like `Backbone.noConflict()`.

Comment: Btw, did you look at [Require.js 2.0](http://tagneto.blogspot.fr/2012/05/requirejs-20-released-onward-amd.html)? It solves your kind of problems. Also take a look at the "Upgrading require.js" guide, you'll see a lot of useful stuff.

Comment: How are you loading your moudules? Can you post your main.js to see how dependencies are being declared?

Comment: @GabrielJürgens  I did fix the question. Actually I have just one problem regarding the global variable. and Backbone.noConflict() does not fix my problem. I mean the Backbone is global.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine. I did fix the question. Actually I have just one problem regarding the global variable. and Backbone.noConflict() does not fix my problem. I mean the Backbone is global.

Answer (score 1):

these will be global by default due to the way the libraries themselves (backbone, etc) are written - they explicitly use the global space (b/c well, that's how js works). have you tried [the AMD-forks](https://github.com/amdjs) of these libs?

maybe a better option as noted by Florian in comments above is to use Require2.0 as it now ships with a ["shim" feature](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.0#wiki-shim) which helps you work with non-AMD libs... though i'm not sure that will eliminate the globals.

fwiw, unless you have specific reasons to avoid the globals, they usually aren't that big of a deal.

Comment: I am trying to use shim feature, but can I tell to requirejs that a module is already defined? if yes, how? for eaxmple shim: {
                'jquery'} it looks in baseUrl but actually is it already loaaded.

Comment: require won't try to load a module it has already loaded. if you are loading jquery using require, you should be fine. if you are loading jquery via require AND standard script tag, then you could end up with two copies in your page. I *think* if you load jquery first require will see it has already been loaded (technically "defined" as a module) and not try to load it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use amd versions of those libraries that are wrapped into AMD modules, that should avoid the use of global variables:

https://github.com/amdjs/backbone

https://github.com/amdjs/underscore

They are maintained by James Burke, the author of RequireJS.

Hope this solves your problem!